# Override a sealed classes toString

Tags: c#, listbox, overriding, tostring

I have what I think is a simple question, but cannot find a simple answer.

I wanted to override the `toString()` method in `System.IO.FileInfo`; however, my usual ways of doing this don't seem to work.

I had thought of creating a new class which inherited from `System.IO.FileInfo`, but I cannot do this because the method is defined as sealed `public sealed class FileInfo : FileSystemInfo`.

I tried creating a partial class; however, since `System.IO` is in a different assembly I wasn't able to get it to work properly.

I even considered creating an extension method, and while that worked for creating a new method I wasnt able to simply override `toString()`.

---

Essentially, in the currently implementation I have a listbox, and its items are a collection of `FileInfo` items. Currently the `toString()` just prints the name, but I wanted to have an entry with a little more information.

I understand a `DataGridView` would be more appropriate, but I don't really need multi-columns. I thought I could just set the ListBox's `DisplayMember` to my extension method... but, now I realize `DisplayMember` needs to point to a property... not a method.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: You could always just make a class that contains FileInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not override them. You can write your own `FileInfo`-Class and implement all FileInfo methods in this class. Than you can write your own `toString()` method.

This would be the easiest solution:

```
public class OwnFileInfo
{
    private FileInfo fileInfo;

    public OwnFileInfo(string fileName)
    {
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
    }

    public FileStream Create()
    {
        return fileInfo.Create();
    }

    // ... more methods
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thank-you for your quick reply. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank-you, I adapted your answer... and some of the other suggestion. I was way too caught up wanting to override the toString() and didnt see out of the box to this solution. Thanks for the insight!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is *impossible* to override the member of a sealed class.  The whole *point* of sealing a class is to *actively prevent* anyone from overriding any of the members, allowing the type to rely on the exact implementations provided.

In your specific case the solution is to simply not bind objects of type `FileInfo`.  Convert the collection of objects into something else (This can be as simple as a call to `Enumerable.Select`.), and bind *that* to your control, rather than binding the `FileInfo` objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider decorating the `FileInfo` class

```
public MyFileInfo 
{
   private FileInfo _fileInfo;

   public FileAttributes Attributes { get { return _fileInfo.Attributes; }  set { _fileInfo.Attributes = value; } }

   // other file info methods

   public override ToString()
   {
      // your code
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried inheriting from FileInfo, but it wouldnt let me since it was sealed. I would have had to inherit from FileSystemInfo. The container suggestion above I think may work for me. Thanks for the quick reply.